# DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED for some devices

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get a message when a smart-card reader is connected to the system, or when a card is inserted to the reader. It appears that I get `WM_DEVICECHANGE` with `wParam` set to `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` for both of those devices along with many other devices. But this isn't very useful as you can't determine what device is inserted/removed. So, I need to use `RegisterDeviceNotification` to register notifications of a device. One of the arguments to that function is the type of `GUID`, so I checked the GUID for these devices from the device manager:

[image: Device Manager]

[image: Guid for reader]

[image: Guid for card]

Here's my WndProc:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND   const hwnd,
    UINT   const message,
    WPARAM const wParam,
    LPARAM const lParam)
{
    // Handles we free later.
    static HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotifySCard;
    static HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotifyReader;

    // GUIDs to register.
    constexpr GUID readerGuid = 
        { 0x50dd5230, 0xba8a, 0x11d1, 
            {0xbf, 0x5d, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x05, 0xf5, 0x30} };

    constexpr GUID scardGuid  = 
        { 0x990a2bd7, 0xe738, 0x46c7, 
            {0xb2, 0x6f, 0x1c, 0xf8, 0xfb, 0x9f, 0x13, 0x91} };

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            // Register the GUIDs
            DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE filter{};
            filter.dbcc_size = sizeof(filter);
            filter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
            filter.dbcc_classguid = readerGuid;

            hDevNotifyReader = RegisterDeviceNotificationW(hwnd, &filter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
            if (!hDevNotifyReader)
                OutputDebugStringW(L"Can't register reader notifications\n");

            filter.dbcc_classguid = scardGuid;
            hDevNotifySCard = RegisterDeviceNotificationW(hwnd, &filter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);

            if (!hDevNotifySCard)
                OutputDebugStringW(L"Can't register scard notifications\n");

            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                    if (reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_HDR*>(lParam)->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE)
                    {
                        auto const dev_struct = reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE const*>(lParam);

                        if (dev_struct->dbcc_classguid == readerGuid)
                            OutputDebugStringW(L"Reader connected\n");
                        else if (dev_struct->dbcc_classguid == scardGuid)
                            OutputDebugStringW(L"Card connected\n");
                        else
                            OutputDebugStringW(L"Unknonw GUID\n");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        std::wostringstream stream;
                        stream << L"Device type: " << std::hex << reinterpret_cast<DEV_BROADCAST_HDR*>(lParam)->dbch_devicetype << L'\n';
                        OutputDebugStringW(stream.str().c_str());
                    }
                    return TRUE;

                case DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED:
                    OutputDebugStringW(L"A device has been added to or removed from the system.\n");
                    return TRUE;
                
                default: {
                    std::wostringstream stream;
                    stream << std::hex <<
                        L"wParam=" << wParam << L", lParam=" << lParam << L'\n';

                    OutputDebugStringW(stream.str().c_str());
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            if (hDevNotifyReader)
                UnregisterDeviceNotification(hDevNotifyReader);
            if (hDevNotifySCard)
                UnregisterDeviceNotification(hDevNotifySCard);

            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Now I get the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` message when the reader is inserted, which is good. But I don't get the same for the smart card itself. I still get `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` for the both of them. So, why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need look for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SMARTCARD` which is `{084f9363-e31a-4bde-9ca5-6fa0d86e009f}`

Comment: also instead 2 calls for `RegisterDeviceNotificationW` you can do single call with `DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES` flags and dump all interface `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` events

Comment: @RbMm Where is `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SMARTCARD` defined? I couldn't find it. I tried it manually with `{084f9363-e31a-4bde-9ca5-6fa0d86e009f}`, it doesn't help the problem. I still don't get the messages.

Comment: @RbMm When I call `RegisterDeviceNotificationW` with `DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES`, what do I set the guid?

Comment: this defined in *scfilter.sys* i give you suggestion - spy for **all** interfaces - `DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES` and dump what you got. however because your smart card in not recognized by windows (unknown card) - may be scfilter notcreate device for card and not register this interface

Comment: `static DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE dbd = { sizeof(dbd), DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE };
   _hDevNot = RegisterDeviceNotificationW(hwnd, &dbd, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);`

Comment: [*The dbcc_classguid member is ignored.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerdevicenotificationw)

Comment: @ayxan-haqverdili `GUID_DEVCLASS_SMARTCARDREADER` is defined in `devguid.h` (along with a bunch of `GUIDE_DEVCLASS_*` defines) but `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SMARTCARD` doesn't appear to have a good definition anywhere, and I'm not even sure if it's a real thing or not. The rest of the `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_*` defines are in individual files such as `Ntddmou.h` and `Ntddstor.h` so I'd guess there's probably some `Ntscard.h` or something that defines it, but it aint in `winscard.h` so... *shrug*.

Comment: If you're sure it's legit, you can probably include `devuid.h` and define it thus:
`DEFINE_GUID( GUID_DEVINTERFACE_SMARTCARD,    0x084f9363L, 0xe31a, 0x4bde, 0x9c, 0xa5, 0x6f, 0xa0, 0xd8, 0x6e, 0x00, 0x9f );`

Comment: (`winioctl.h` also defines a bunch of the same stuff as `Ntddstor..h`)